# What is the product between these two matrices called, and is it possible?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Let $$H = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \end{pmatrix}, W = \begin{pmatrix} w_{11} & w_{12} \\ w_{21} & w_{22} \\ w_{31} & w_{32} \end{pmatrix}$$

I understand that there exists a tensor product, but unless I'm mistaken it won't achieve what I'm aiming for. I want something like this:

$$ P = \begin{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}w_{11} + a_{21}w_{12} \\ a_{11}w_{21} + a_{21}w_{22} \\ a_{11}w_{31} + a_{21}w_{32} \end{pmatrix} \ \begin{pmatrix} a_{12}w_{11} + a_{22}w_{12} \\ a_{12}w_{21} + a_{22}w_{22} \\ a_{12}w_{31} + a_{22}w_{32} \end{pmatrix} \ \begin{pmatrix} a_{13}w_{11} + a_{23}w_{12} \\ a_{13}w_{21} + a_{23}w_{22} \\ a_{13}w_{31} + a_{23}w_{32} \end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}$$

Mathematically, is there a definition for this product? I can't seem to break it down into known operations either. Indeed, this can be achievable programmatically via some for-loops, however I'm hoping there's some kind of numpy function that helps me achieve this. As far as I can understand, this is not a tensor product.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, this is just the matrix product $WH$. This can be implemented with numpy as `np.dot(W,H)`, or `W@H`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice this. Thanks.